# Set order of bars for stacked barcharts in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given a data example like this:

```
  city     a     b
0   bj  4130  5505
1   sh  3869  4626
2   wh  3490  1511
3   sz  2566  1914
4   cd  1780  2315
```

I have used the following code to plot a stacked barchart:

```
dfm <- melt(df[,c('city', 'a', 'b')], id.vars = 1)
dfm
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = city, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(aes(x = city, y = value, label = value),
                  position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 2.5)
```

Out:
[image]

Now I would like to set a decreasing order of bars based on sum of `a` and `b`, how could I do that? At this case, it should be `bj, sh, wh, sz, cd`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder `city` before melting:

```r
df <- structure(list(city = c("bj", "sh", "wh", "sz", "cd"), a = c(4130L, 
                                                                   3869L, 3490L, 2566L, 1780L), b = c(5505L, 4626L, 1511L, 1914L, 
                                                                                                      2315L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df$city <- reorder(df$city, -(df$a + df$b))

dfm <- melt(df[,c('city', "a", "b")], id.vars = 1)

ggplot(dfm, aes(x = city, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(aes(x = city, y = value, label = value),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 2.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I tried with `aes(x = reorder(city, -value)`, it seems also works.

Comment: Good to know. Just checked. Reorder simply uses the mean when there are more than one value per category which gives the same order as taking the sum.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the x-axis to factor and defined the order by the levels.

```
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = factor(city, levels = c('bj', 'sh', 'wh', 'sz', 'cd')), y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  geom_text(aes(x = city, y = value, label = value),
            position = position_stack(vjust = .5), size = 2.5)
```